# How to apply post filter in ElasticSearch that filters out certain values?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to filter the stats returned by the extended stats aggregation. I basically need to filter out all values where the `avg` is 0.

Below is a sample query where I need to filter these values. I think I should be applying a [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html). However, I am not sure how should I apply the post filter when I want to filter out a particular value. Could you please help?

```
    "aggs": {
      "variable_grp": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "variable",
          "size": 200,
          "order": { "stats.avg": "asc" }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "stats": {
            "extended_stats": { "field": "value_num" }
          }
        }
      }
    }, 
    "size":0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `bucket_selector` pipeline aggregation to achieve what you want:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "variable_grp": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variable",
        "size": 200,
        "order": {
          "stats.avg": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "stats": {
          "extended_stats": {
            "field": "value_num"
          }
        },
        "avg_gt_0": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "avgStats": "stats.avg"
            },
            "script": "params.avgStats > 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Works like a charm!